# UICollectionView sizeForItemAt crash

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I got this error and have no idea how to solve it. Why is this crashing? Wanted to put it in center of view, but even with test 10,10 cgpoint its crashing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to center?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems like your collection view data source does not have any elements. Check that our first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to fully understand the problem with these codes but I guess you should try add that delegate **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

like this

```
class TestController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
// codes
}
```